# AttributeError: 'Page1' object has no attribute 'attributes'

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to put my window above and I used `self.attributes("-topmost", True)` for this with `tkinter`. But it raises

> Attribute Error: 'Page1' object has no attribute 'attributes'`

I used `self.lift()` instead this but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

```
import tkinter as tk

x=input("Type something")

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        
class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self) 

    buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
    b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
    b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift) 

    b1.pack(side="left")
    b2.pack(side="left")
    b3.pack(side="left") 


    p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.attributes('-topmost', True)` applies on window, not frame. So use `root.attributes(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set this on your root Tk.

```
    def show(self):
        self.master.master.attributes("-topmost", True)
```

Comment: Better use `self.winfo_toplevel().attributes("-topmost", True)`.